# set different bootstrap labels (color) depending on backend information (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set the different label colors, depending on the status of my server. I am using AngularJS and Java at the backend. I use the variable {{server.state}}. It returns a string with the information "online" or "offline". Depending on the state i want to set the bootstrap level to "label label-success" or "label label-danger".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-class` to dynamically set the class of the element. The syntax is:

```
ng-class="{className1: expression1, className2: expression2}"
```

Also, don't forget to put the hyphenated class name (bootstrap uses those extensively) in quotes:

```
<div class="label" 
     ng-class="{'label-success': server.state === 'online', 'label-danger': server.state === 'offline'}">
   {{server.state}}
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

For more complicated logic, put the logic in the controller's function that returns a list of space-delimited class names:

```
$scope.stateToClass = function(){
   if ($scope.server.state === 'online' || something.else === 'foo'){
      return "label label-success";
   } else {
      return "label label-danger";
   }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
<div ng-class="stateToClass()">
   {{server.state}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That works! Is it possible, to define, that the label for online is green and for everything else is red? (If i have more states for an offline state, like "error, stopped" etc.), so that i don't have to define every single state?

Comment: This is a normal comparison expression. Yes. Do `!== 'online'`

Comment: I discovered one problem: ng-class="{'label-success': server.state === 'onlineA' || modem.state === 'onlineB', 'label-danger': modem.state !== 'onlineA' || modem.state !== 'onlineB'}"> This is not working. If the server is in the online state (A or B) it has a "danger" label.

Comment: This goes beyond the scope of the question - you understand now how this works in principle. Next, work out your logic (look again at your logic and you'll see the problem with negation and `||`). If the logic is too complicated to be put in the expression in the View, create a function exposed on the scope that returns the class names - I updated my question to that effect.